# display only 3 foreach result per row

Tags: php, foreach

i have script as follows

```
$output="<table class='products'><tr>"; 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
    //Outputs the image and other data
    $output.= "<td>
    <img src=http://localhost/zack/sqlphotostore/images/"   .$info['photo'] ." width=323px ></img> 
    <b>Name:</b> ".$info['name'] . "
    <b>Email:</b> ".$info['email'] . " 
    <b>Phone:</b> ".$info['phone'] . "</td> "; 
}
$output.="<tr></table>";
print $output;
?>
```

it shows all results in long horizontal line  how do i break the results so that they show 
in new row after 3 count.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a counter and start a new row every time it reaches a multiple of 3.

```
$counter = 0;
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
   if ($counter++ % 3 == 0) {
       if ($counter > 0) {
           $output .= "</tr>";
       }
       $output .= "<tr>";
   }
   // stuff
}
if ($counter > 0) {
    $output .= "</tr>";
}

$output .= "</table>";
```

**Please note:** It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Answer (score 4):

Keep a counter, and output a new table row every 3 images

```
$output="<table class='products'>"; 

$counter = 0;
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{  
    if( $counter % 3 == 0 )
        $output .= '<tr>';

    $output .= "<td>";
    $output .= "<img src=http://localhost/zack/sqlphotostore/images/".$info['photo'] ." width=323px ></img>";
    $output .= "<b>Name:</b> ".$info['name'];
    $output .= "<b>Email:</b> ".$info['email'];
    $output .= "<b>Phone:</b> ".$info['phone']."</td> ";

    if( $counter % 3 == 0)
         $output .= "</tr>";

    $counter++;
}
$output.="</table>";
print $output;
?>
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer, aside from how you implemented it? +1 for correct/great answer, but know that it's a duplicate of one that was posted 4 minutes prior.